# memory allocation issues when merging two large datasets in r

Tags: r, memory-management, merge, out-of-memory, large-data

I need to merge two relatively large datasets in `R`. `A` has *651,052 observations and 118 variables* and `B` contains *38,208 observations and 41 variables* and I, literally, cannot reduce the data size further. Applying `object.size()` function reveals that these two datasets occupy *610 Mb and 13 Mb* in memory respectively.

The machine I am using has a 64-bit CPU and 32GB of RAM. Yet, when trying to merge these files `R` shoots memory allocation errors: `Error: cannot allocate vector of size x Mb`! I have checked similar posts on SO and tried many of the proposed solutions but none of them were effective in my case: I have checked the memory limit using `memory.limit()` which returns `32684` which shows that R has access to the max available memory on my computer. Also, using the `merge` function from `data.table` package could not solve the issue either and produced memory allocation error.

I was able to divide `A` into two parts and merge (which is actually a `left_join`) each part separately with `B` following the blow procedure:

```
# open fresh R session

load(A)
load(B)

part_1 <- left_join(first_half_A, B)
save(part_1)

# close R
```

```
# re-open R

load(A)
load(B)

part_2 <- left_join(second_half_A, B)
save(part_2)

# close R
```

The resulting parts occupy around `200 Mb` on the disk but when I load them in `R` they grow dramatically in size and occupy almost `25 Gb` which, contrary to my hopes to have these parts in more manageable sizes when reloaded in `R` in this fashion, prevents me from having both of them loaded so I can combine them using `bind_rows`.

Considering that adding extra RAM or using platforms such as AWS would not be an option, what do you suggest to overcome this issue? A solution that would preferably not enter the `SQL` world is much appreciated.

PS. below you can see the output of `sessionInfo()` on my machine:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 16299)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Netherlands.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Netherlands.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Netherlands.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                        
[5] LC_TIME=English_Netherlands.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.2 tools_3.6.2    knitr_1.28     xfun_0.12
```

**First Update**

What helped me accomplish the merger was to change the type of some variables where possible mainly from `numeric` to `integer` which lead to further reduction in data size. However, the memory allocation problem still remains as the merged data set, which contains 47M rows and 124 vars, while taking only 235 Mb on disk occupies the whole 32 Gb of RAM when loaded in a fresh R session and leaves no more space for the coming analyses which are also computationally heavy such as estimating multiple mixed models. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions regarding this situation which will help me proceed.

Comment: Are you really sure that you are not doing an unintended cartesian join?

Comment: I once had a problem that is similar to yours and it turned out to be what @Roland suggests. I have worked with data sets that are considerably larger than yours and didn't have any problems (with similar computer specs). Maybe try to do the join on only a few lines and check the output.

Comment: @Roland @MKR, thanks for your comments. That's intentional indeed, every observation in `A` should be matched with multiple observations from `B`. For instance the `part_1` that I explained above would contain around 22M observations.

Comment: Well, if you do cartesian joins you need more memory. I'd suggest you consider carefully how you can avoid the cartesian join.

Comment: The object size appears to not being so big... But have you explored alternatives as bigmemory, bigmatrix alternatives?

Comment: @hamagust as far as I know those packages handle data in matrix form. I cannot afford it as I have categorical vars in my data as well.